# Keep data validation and drop down same after updating Google sheets using gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, gspread

I am working on an existing script made by someone else which updates few google sheets. I am relatively new to Python. Everything is fine, but when lets say it updates an existing row the dropdown option or conditional formatting is also removed & when a new row is added I want the conditional formatting to apply to that row as well but haven't been able to find a solution.
Any document / solution I can read through to understand if it is possible and how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Here [the document](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/) you need to read.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your situation of `when lets say it updates an existing row the dropdown option or conditional formatting is also removed & when a new row is added I want the conditional formatting to apply to that row as well`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike so lets say row 1 to 10 are already populated for a sheet and column B till row 10 has an dropdown option with different values. Now I have to update row 2 because there is new data and add new row no 11. What is happening is when row 2 is updating that drop down option is removed which I want to avoid and new row 11 doesn't have that option which I want to add.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Thanks for the document. I had gone through this before but couldn't find specific examples for what I was looking for. As per your experience is it even possible to do? or is there a section in the document which I may have missed talks about that part?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.